# How to start a sentence with "To name a few"? or any alternative phrase for an academic document?

Tags: american-english

How I can start a sentence with "To name a few"? I have read [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63273/meaning-of-the-phrase-to-name-a-few).
I am writing a paper and for saying how important is the topic, I want to add a few examples. I do not want to list everything and want to just mention two examples with emphasizing on this point that these two are just examples and there are a lot of usages for the topic. I chose "To name a few" but it is usually used at the end of sentence. How I can use it at the beginning or any alternative phrase?

Comment: Generally, it is not at the beginning of a sentence since it refers to items in the sentence. To name a few of the interesting topics I have found would take too much space.

Answer (score 0):

For example/instance

> For example, we've worked with clients x, y, and z.

Including

> Including information from x, y, and z allow us to take a deeper look at j.

Although + Because

> Although examples x and y indicate these factors, we can safely ignore them because of z.

Comment: Thanks Robin. If I want to start or use the phrase "to name a few", how I can do that?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your title and was thinking of just alternate phrases. I don't know how frequently people would start a sentence with "To name a few". It's pretty much always used as an ending, because it lacks an initial frame of reference. You have to proceed it because otherwise people don't know what you're naming a few of. 

"We have clients around the globe. To name a few, we've worked with x, y, and z."

But normally you'd just say

"We've worked with clients around the globe like x, y, and z, to name a few.